# Can fast page mode depend on the first data retrieved?

Tags: memory, performance, chip

As early as the seventies, some computers used RAM in page mode, in which you can read two or more words from sequential locations in rapid succession by only supplying the column address once, and then just supplying the row address of each location.

In that mode, can the decision whether to read a second word, depend on the contents of the first?

That is, can you, with 1970s technology, read one word, check its contents (with fast hardwired logic, not expecting software to be fast enough for such), and on the basis of that, decide whether to read a second word in fast page mode?

Or is it the case that by the time the first word is read, plus a couple of gate delays for a minimum analysis, it's too late; to meet the timing constraints of page mode, you have to already have started the process of reading the second word if you are going to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> As early as the seventies, some computers used RAM in page mode,

Just the other way around, 1976 page mode RAM (MK4116) was available, and subsequently computers did use it, so make that the late 70s.

> in which you can read two or more words from sequential locations

No, they did not have to be in sequence, all they needed to be is within the same *page*, hence the name.

> in rapid succession by only supplying the column address once, and then just supplying the row address of each location.

(A little nitpicking The other way around, it is row address (RAS) first and column address (CAS) next. With keeping RAS active, the row (page) was held within the read/write buffers as long as desired)

> In that mode, can the decision whether to read a second word, depend on the contents of the first?

Sure, why not. Just latch the last used row address and if the actual access matches the last, skip the row addressing and continue with the column address.

> That is, can you, with 1970s technology, read one word, check its contents (with fast hardwired logic, not expecting software to be fast enough for such), and on the basis of that, decide whether to read a second word in fast page mode?

Oh, I see multiple possible logic issues in these assumptions:

- For one, 1970s hardware isn't less capable than today's. The underlaying logic is still the same.
- Second, hardware of the same time scale will always be fast enough to handle hardware features of the same time, otherwise, why bother to create such feature?
- And last, software (contemporary on contemporary hardware) will always be too slow to cope with a sum cycle issue.

> Or is it the case that by the time the first word is read, plus a couple of gate delays for a minimum analysis, it's too late; to meet the timing constraints of page mode, you have to already have started the process of reading the second word if you are going to?

There are no timing constrains. A page is held open as long as RAS is asserted. There is infinite time to check whatsoever, If the check succeeds go ahead with CAS addressing, if it fails, insert a RAS cycle.

---

## Real World Usage

Now, these RAMs where clock less. No central clocking existed nor was it needed. Just respect the timing. In the real world of clocked microprocessors, everything had to be within the borders set by such a clock. This clock usually not only synchronises the CPU to all its devices, but also drives many other things, like timers or video. Thus it might be hard to do so.

So instead of varying cycle length according to the access pattern, the clock cycle was designed to fit the fastest operation (here RAM in page mode access), and wait cycles where inserted whenever additional time was needed.

Lets take the original **MK4116-2** with **375 ns access time** - that's the time the  hip needs at least to perform a whole read or write cycle with full addressing. So whenever a processor starts a read cycle it will have to wait this time before using the result. On a 6502 with it's symmetric clock and reading in the second half, this translates to about 1 MHz operation - on a Z80 it's be about 4 MHz (*1).

Now when the row address is set, a **page mode cycle** can be done in as little as **175 ns**, or close to half of that. So using a clock fitted to this cycle, and inserting one additional wait cycle whenever the page changes looks like a natural solution, doesn't it?

Of course we need to increase the timing for other delays - for example to detect if the page part of an address has changed or not. A comparator in general is a complex ting, but we do not need to know about the magnitude, just equal or not, and the XOR function delivers exactly this. `A XOR B` delivers a nice `low` whenever both are equal. So two 7486 will nicely compare two values of up to 8 bit. ORed together we get a nice signal telling us that

*we need to insert a RAS cycle* which is

- activating the `WAIT`signal for our CPU
- deasserting `RAS`
- tunnelling the row address (upper 7 bits) onto the chip (`A0..6`)
- latching it for the next comparison
- reasserting `RAS`
- and let the RAM do its work

the next (or only) cycle is **then is the CAS cycle**

- deasserting `WAIT`
- putting the column address (lower 7 bits) onto `A0..6`
- asserting `CAS`
- let the RAM do its work

At the end of that cycle the CPU will sample the data lines and happy read whatever is stored(*2). All taking 1 cycle if the page was 'open', two if not.

**Bottom line, the CPU can run at roughly double the speed the RAM would otherwise allow, and is braked down to 'regular' speed whenever addresses are jumping.**

Nothing comes for free, this additional circuitry does eat up some time (*3). Each level of TTL can be counted as ~10-15ns, so our two level decoder will eat up 30ns for its decision. By using the open collector 74266 XNOR we can reduce this to a single level using a wired-OR. So a mere 15 ns overhead isn't a bad thing, is it?

So with a Z80, we could switch from a 4 MHz Z80A to a 8 MHz Z80H and even realize a good part of that higher clock frequency, as all internal operations and all consecutive (near by) RAM access will now run at full speed, while random access (outside the page) will only add one wait cycle to the three basic cycles(*4), thus only slowing it down by 1/3rd - heck, even with no page mode we have gained much speed - but that's ofc another story (4).

---

If it's so easy, then

## why hasn't it be used more?

Simple, because CPU structure and machine design would diminish the results.

**First, it needs a faster CPU**. For a 4 MHz Z80A, using page mode doesn't make any difference, as it can't use the shorter access time at all.

**Next we still need RAM refresh**. So at least every 10 ms a row needs to be refreshed to keep it's content. That means a minimum of 10,000 full refresh cycle need to be inserted additional, each of them killing our preset row address with a 99% (*6) chance, resulting in an additional wait state for the next CPU access even if its within the same page from the CPUs view point.

**CPU access is only in pat continuous**. While opcodes and operands are in order, every data access is not, requiring a wait state at the data access and another at the begin of the instruction.

**Further some CPUs will make it more complicated** (by being more comfortable in the first place). The Z80 inserts a refresh cycle with every instruction. Thus, after reading an opcode, the whole glory of above will hit - way more often than needed(*7,8).

**And then there is third party access**. Many (home/early) computers not only map video memory into the CPU address space, but video rather uses CPU RAM for video data. Especially during a line displayed on CRT, the the video circuitry will access the RAM several times, making not only the CPU wait, but also most likely changing the page address, thus requiring the next CPU access to start with a `RAS` cycle and its wait state.

Bottom line, using page mode makes only sense when there is a gain - most likely speed - but results start to diminish depending on the machines design, while additional cost for a faster CPU (and circuitry) is to be added regardless of gain.

---

*1 - doesn't that fall nicely in the usual ratio of common Z80 vs. 6502 comparisons? It's all about RAM access, isn't it?

*2 - Writing works with exactly the same timing, so our circuitry doesn't need to care about.

*3 - But so is all selecting etc.

*4 - With multiple banks of 4116, there's even another optimization trick. One could send the page address (row) to all banks, thus opening the same bank in all chips, making access to all pages within one cycle. Assuming a 64 KiB system using MK4116, a program loop at address 0100..017F can access data at 0100..017F, 4100..418F, 8100..818F and C100..C17F without a wait. That's 512 bytes of 'fast' RAM :))

*5 - The exact calculations are a bit more complex here.

*6 - More exact 127/128 or 99.2%

*7 - The refresh can be somewhat delayed, as the MK4116 guarantees data hold time of 2ms. Within these 2ms all 128 rows need to be refreshed only once. With an average of ~10µs between refresh cycles we would be on the safe side. Assuming 10 cycles per instruction on a Z80 as average, this means, on a 4 MHz Z80 doing an refresh every fourth instruction would be good (on average). Leaving out the refresh for 3 out of 4 times might be easy, but this also means we would need an external refresh counter, killing the advantage of the Z80. Or we go ahead and surpres two out of three cycles. Since 3 is prime, we will run thru all 128 row addresses within the needed time - now jumping like a rabbit instead of crawling like a slug. Still, it needs two additional TTL.

*8 - The wait state can be avoided with some additional circuitry, but that again increases the chip count

Comment: Page mode was used in ZX Spectrum: "ula" was fetching both pixel byte and attribute byte from a single page, setting RAS address once and then making two consecutive CAS accesses. That allowed ZX Spectrum to support some bandwidth for the CPU even during video data fetching. Otherwise the CPU would be stopped up to the end of video line fetch (~128 clocks) whenever it tried to access video ("slow") memory.

Comment: When I'd looked at data sheets, it didn't seem like the savings for same-page accesses was that great.  I've thought for quite awhile that machines like the C64 could have benefited greatly from page-mode access if each character time (8 cycles of the master clock) were subdivided to use 3+2 cycles to fetch two bytes of video data and 3 cycles for a byte of CPU data.  If address wires were arranged so that the columns were e.g. A0 and A9-A15, that could have avoided the need to have the video stall the CPU while also avoiding the need for a separate color-attribute-data bus.

Comment: @supercat I found a [MK4116 Data Sheet](https://console5.com/techwiki/images/8/85/MK4116.pdf) and it's even better than my memory was. Check the tables. The guranteed time for a full read or write cycle, **tRC is 375ns**, while a page mode cycle is less than half thereof, as **tPC is 170 ns*. So after having opend a page, every subsequent action within the same page is done in less than 200ns. Keep in mind that's what the RAM allows. How much of the potential can be realized depends a lot on the machine architecture choosen. It will go far beyond a RC question to detail out what can be done.

Comment: @Raffzahn: Okay, I think I see my confusion.  The access time from /CAS is still 2/3 as great the access time from /RAS (which is what I'd remembered) but one gains time on the tail end of each cycle because /CAS has almost no recovery time.  That would suggest that systems that interleave CPU and video cycles could have benefited enormously by fetching pairs of bytes from video memory, and those that perform bursts of video accesses could have benefited even more.

Comment: @supercat I'sd say it'S half (175 vs. 375), but yes, it ofc only results in savings when used. so a doulbe byte access, like a character and some attribute byte at one would need 25% less time. The question is rather if that can be turned into a usable gain. The VICII with its character buffer would be a way to use it. With a memory base clock twice the CPU clock, kind of a 'double pumped' access could habe been realised, cuting the time the CPU is stoped during 'bad lines' into half. Since that's every 8th line, this would result in a ~5% faster CPU

Comment: @Raffzahn: If the VIC-II had been designed around double-fetches, both bad lines and the need for an attribute RAM could have been eliminated.  Using a 40x16 shift register, odd scan lines (starting just before the first line of display) could fetch character/attribute pairs and feed them to the shift register while data from the shift register was sent to the display.  Even scan lines would read two bitmap bytes for each character and display one with the received attribute while feeding the other bitmap byte and attribute values out to the shift register.

Comment: Nitpicking right back at you: "A page is held open as long as RAS is asserted." ... except that there is a maximum RAS pulse width specified for at least some DRAM chips (e.g. the 4116 has a max width of 10us).

Comment: You're right. There is an upper boundry ... then again, <even-more-nitpicking-mode>it's 32us for the MK4114</even-more-nitpicking-mode> :)) I can even think of a way where tRAS is overstretched - like due a burst refresh setup. But given, while it may be hard to archieve in a real world microprocesser system, it's possible :))

Answer (score 5):

The earliest point at which a device could supply a new column address would generally be when it reads the data from the old one.  If one added logic that added an extra 20ns to the time required for the chip to receive a valid address after it output data, that would add 20ns to the total time required for the chip to perform both reads.  Using column mode might still allow slightly better performance than would be possible without it, but adding any extra delay to column mode would reduce the benefits to the point that it may no longer be worth using.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not true. Due the inherent need for a faster CPU that is needed to realize the gain of a shorter access time due page mode, such a machine will *always* be faster than onenot using page mode. With late 1970s technology, a design around a page mode memory subsystem will yield 60+% more performance than not using page mode. The question isn't about being faster, but about is it worth it.

Comment: @Raffzahn: When I've looked at the data sheets for 1980s DRAMs, the differences in access times from /RAS to output vs. from column-address-valid to output weren't huge; about a 33% savings if I recall.  I suppose there could also be an advantage at the tail end of each cycle by eliminating recovery time, but my point is that the getting maximum speed advantage from performing multiple accesses on the same row requires that column addresses be ready before data is received; any propagation delay between data received on one fetch and the column address used on the next will slow things down.

Comment: @Raffzahn: Also don't forget that systems with late 70s technology, e.g. 6502 CPUs, generally were *slower* than the RAMs - on the 6502 homecomputers, the videobuffer/refresh access is sandwiched between the CPU accesses.

Comment: @supercat check again - [like here](https://console5.com/techwiki/images/8/85/MK4116.pdf) as a page cycle is less than half of a full RAC/CAS cycle with the original MK4116 from 1976 - there was no page mode before that so it'll be the best base to talk about.

Comment: @dirkt please read blow aner. The question is about what can be realized from using a DRAM in page mode, and that's a clean doubling of speed. That is true on any CPU, no matter if it's a 6502 or whatever.  It's not the RAMs fault if a certain **machine design** did hinder the use of page mode.

Comment: @Raffzahn: It's certainly not the RAM's fault. Still, it's also not useful if the CPU can't keep up ... (and that's the answer to "why wasn't page mode used, if it was so much better?")

Comment: Also, @dirkt CPUs wheren't slower than RAM in the 1970. They where in the same area, usually evan a bit faster. DRAM was slow compared to that. a 6502 was available in 2 MHz already in 1978 - but there here no DRAMs to go with a 6502 that fast, as it would have requred 200ns cycle time. To use the maximum possible speed, SRAM was needed. we're not talking a big difference, but it has been that way all the time.

Comment: @dirkt Sure, btu the CPU cs could keep up with page mode. It's not the CPUs fault if the enginer did choose a design that can't keep up. Usually that's a marketing decision to make it cheap instead of fast.

Comment: @Raffzahn: The Atari 400/800 ran at chroma/2 (1.79Mhz), but any video accesses would stall the CPU.  A more common design for 6502 machines was to perform two memory operations per CPU cycle, one of which would be devoted to video.  On many machines of that era, an ability to access two bytes of video memory per cycle would have offered sufficiently obvious advantages that someone would have done it if it were easy.

Comment: @supercat we're talking home computers - that's the area where we had a race to the bottom to deliver cheaper machines, not better or faster ones. Blame it on Tramiels price war.

Comment: @Raffzahn: If machines weren't trying to compete on graphics and sound, they wouldn't have had the capabilities they did.  Further, if the VIC-II had used page mode, that would have eliminated the need for a 1Kx4 attribute RAM, its separate bus, and the 4066 to allow CPU access on the main bus.

Comment: @supercat well, they didin't, or do you realy see where the C64 did put up any effort against the older Atari? It was an intermediate solution rushed to market. Competition only happened in marketing and sales price. Not in quality and even less in innovation.

Comment: @Raffzahn: The Commodore 64 allowed colors to be specified on a per-character basis, at the expense of adding at least two otherwise-unnecessary chips and adding four pins to the VIC-II chip that could otherwise have served other purposes.  Additionally, I doubt the C64 would have included a sound chip with a configurable filter if it weren't trying to compete on sound.

Comment: @supercat Well, sounds like a true fanboy :)

Comment: @Raffzahn: I had one back in the day and thought it was the greatest thing since sliced Cheez-Wiz&reg; brand food product.  It was in some ways better and in other ways worse than the Atari machines, but Commodore was clearly trying to compete in the graphics and sound arenas and their advertising reflected that.