# Unused RAM Chips on x86 machines

Tags: ibm-pc, memory, memory-layout

On classic x86 machines the upper 384 KB of system memory contains video RAM and BIOS ROM Besides other things. Those areas overlay over conventional RAM, so that you can't use all upper memory, but only some areas.

Does this mean that on machines with 1 MB of RAM some parts of it (and hence the associated DRAM ICs) will never be used?

Comment: At least some PCs supported remapping the 384K to just above 1MB so it could be usable. Some also supported using some of this RAM for BIOS shadowing.

Comment: Short version: you're assuming the memory was mapped continuously. That was not usually the case. Machines sold as having 1MB of RAM had that RAM mapped with an address gap between 640KB and 1MB, precisely to account for the needs BIOS and attached devices.

Comment: The original 8088/8086 based machines couldn't address anything above 1Mb having only 20 address lines. If they had 1Mb of RAM it had to shadow the BIOS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does this mean that on machines with 1 MiB of RAM some parts of it (and hence the associated DRAM ICs) will never be used?

No. For one, at this time Machines did not come with 1 MiB, but 640 KiB at max. Even when 1 MiBit chips where used, they where usually of the 256x4 kind, so 4 of them made up 512 KiB plus another 4 64x4 chips (256 KiBit) adding the remaining 128 KiB. For 8086/88/186 machines there was no reason in having more than 640KiB (*1).

With upcoming 80286 machines usage for more than 640 KiB became possible. Early AT still had only 640 KiB Base Memory and everything above 1 MiB was to be added with add on cards. It wasn't until [Chips and Technologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chips_and_Technologies) came up with their [NEAT chipset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEAT_chipset). NEAT being an Acronym for *'**N**ew **E**nhanced **AT**'*. Beside continuing the further integration of prior discrete components like Bus Controllers, Timers or DMA, the NEAT chipset also added logic to support 1 MiB of RAM (or more) with a mapping of 640 KiB at 0..9FFFFh (classic PC address Range) and what's left starting at 100000h (above 1 MiB) into the ATs extended address space.

Timewise this happened ~1986.

Successive chipsets added more features. For example shadowing of BIOS ROMs (*2) and LIM-EMS support with the LEAP chipset. Of course other companies also started to build integrated chipsets. Ultimately this was the start (*3) of today's well known [Northbridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northbridge_(computing)) design of modern PCs.

---

*1 - At least not while being compatible. Non or less compatible machines, like the SIEMENS PC-D did offer a continuous MiB or RAM.

*2 - Already at this time ROM and even more EPROM chips where much slower than RAM. Every BIOS access did slow the machine down. With shadowing the BIOS content got copied into RAM, with write protection acting as fast ROM emulation.

*3 - The SuperXT chipset for 8086 machines was released *after* the NEAT one, despite what the lower chip-id suggests.

Comment: I confirm. Have PC XT motherboard on the table, with 640K physical RAM on it.

Comment: Ok, I have a 286 mainboard here with 1024 KiB of RAM, Phoenix BIOS 3.0. It has CHIPS ICs on board, but it is a pretty obscure board, so I am unsure whether it has any of your mentioned features... I just got it to boot and complain about CMOS settings. Will prep it up more to get a bootable system and see what the Setup program says. Maybe it does the mapping into space above 1 MiB.

Comment: @Arne Can you note down the chip numbers?

Comment: Interestingly, my alas now defunct 286 from ICL (manufactured 87) had a mainboard built mostly from discrete logic rather than an integrated chipset, but all of its memory was in the form of 1MB plugin boards, and it was mapped correctly (or at least HIMEM.SYS reported correct total amount), so it seems that at least some manufacturers did do the mapping without an integrated chipset.

Comment: @Raffzahn: Yes, will do when I am at home.

Comment: @Raffzahn: I actually had a picture on my phone: P82C202, P82A203, P82A204 (I think, the last digit is in the shadow). And there are two more ICs in shadow, I think one of them reads P82C201. The other I can't make out, but all numbers seem to be sequential...

Comment: Ok, I looked up the NEAT, and its number is P82C206. So I figure I have the predecessor. The board indeed looks ancient. I even have two discrete Intel DMA controller ICs.

Comment: @Arne 206 _is_ the NEAT controller. And no, there is no real predecessor. What puzzles me are seperate DMA controllers, as they are already within the 206.

Comment: @Raffzahn I do NOT have the 206 on board. I have 201 through 204 at the least. Here is the datasheet to the 203: http://www.datasheetspdf.com/pdf/759515/CHIPS/P82A203/1 -- That one does NOT include DMA controllers, according to the PDF.

Comment: Also, here is a low res image link to the board I have (picture is not mine): https://www.vogons.org/download/file.php?id=45855&sid=18a24a010e67d38412f1f5f62cc7b55c&mode=view

Comment: I've had DOS machines with more than 640 KiB, but less than 1 MiB.  One had 704 KiB, another 736 KiB with that full amount accessible from DOS by eating into normally reserved (but unused on those machines) video RAM areas.  Another one I had was 768 KiB, but the extra 128 KiB was *only* usable as RAM disk (using the same /E Extended memory flag that was also available on 286+) but I never determined where it mapped, could not find it by scanning the full 1 MiB space and it was an 8088, so did not have XMS nor Gate A20...

Comment: @Raffzahn 206 is not the what makes up for the well-known features of the NEAT chipset. The NEAT chipset is collectively called CS8221, and consists of the 82c211, 82c212 and 82c215 as well as the 82c206 integrated peripheral controller. The '206 integrates the "basic controllers" (DMA, Interrupt, Timer, RTC) and may be paired with neary any ISA chipset or discrete logic mainboard. In fact the '206 and its many clones by different manufacturers survived well into '486 times. The memory mapping & EMS stuff is in the 82c212.

Comment: @MichaelKarcher ?? Not really sure what your point is.

Comment: @Raffzahn I was referring to your comment from 2018-04-03 10:43 which claims "206 *is* the NEAT controller". Arne has a board with the CS8220, which in fact is the direct predecessor of the CS8221 ("NEAT") chipset. The 206 is the least NEATy chip of the four chips comprising the CS8221. While the CS8221 datasheet calls the 206 an "integral part of the CS8221", the 82C206 datasheet clearly suggest the chip to be used in conjunction with the CS8220 chipset (as the CS8221 didn't exist when the 206 was developed and that datasheet was written).

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The area between 640k and 1M was called the Upper Memory Area and could be used via various expedients in MSDOS & DRDOS, e.g. for TSR drivers, RAM disks and the like.</strike>

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_memory_area

If you have a working 1M 8086/8088 machine, you could look at booting MSDOS 5 and trying some HIMEM.SYS config - you should be able to shunt a lot of the OS stuff into high memory and see nearly all 640k free for a program.

Only on a 386, apparently. Or a 286, maybe.

Comment: I don't believe HIMEM.SYS would help here ... apart from the fact that I think it requires a 286 processor to run at all, it dealt with XMS memory, i.e. the stuff above 1MB only. You'd be looking at an EMS driver in this situation, but AFAIK all of them were hardware specific (other than EMM386 et al, which obviously required a 386 or above to work). A machine that did have memory in this area would hopefully be supplied with such a driver, or with a custom DOS version that knows how to use the memory (e.g. the RM Nimbus PC186, which IIRC had a DOS version that could use ~900KB of its 1MB RAM)

Comment: IIRC you can do DOS=HIGH in config.sys when using HIMEM.SYS. But that is all so long ago... ;)

Comment: DOS=HIGH uses the first 64KiB of memory above 1MiB.  But on an 8088 or 8086, there is no memory above 1MiB.  This means DOS=HIGH was useful only on the 80286 and higher, which allowed addressing beyond 1MiB via "Protected Mode".  This is what HIMEM.SYS was for -- it managed the "Extended Memory" above 1MiB (including that very first 64KiB that DOS could use via DOS=HIGH)

Comment: The UMB only worked in the 386 because EMM386 put the processor into virtual 8086 ("v86") mode, a protected mode where it could remap extended memory into the virtual UMB address area. As the 8086/186/286 didn't have this capability, they couldn't do this. The only way that you could use any memory in this region on an 8086 machine would be to have an EMS or RAM-disk board installed (they both existed!)

Comment: You may be right. It was many years ago.

Comment: Rich, ofc there where DOS machines with more than 640 KiB. The 640 KiB border was an arbitary one, only set during boot when DOS detected (and 'formated') its memory. In the early days it was common to have 64 KiB on a memory card jumpered at A0000 so 704 KiB could be made available, or even 736 when using a CGA. Beside the card, all needed was a little programm moving up the last MCB to include the additional memory for DOS. No Highmem or whatsoever needed. It already worked with DOS 1.0

Comment: Similar, certain memory cards that could be jumpered to any 16 KiB border where used to fill up the memory after CGA, allowing to add up to another 192 KiB to a total of ~928 KiB RAM in a standard PC. Here the last MCB was now moved oen paragraph down and a dummy MCB was created to exclude the video RAM (and similar any I/O ROM) followed by one MCB in each further RAM block.